# Symfony2 form entering number range

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

What is the best way to use Symfony2's form builder where users can enter 2 number that ranges from first to last. For instance user wants to enter a Rack number of 2 to 5, and the controller will have to enter into the database rack numbers from 2, 3, 4, and 5. If entered 5-9, then database enters 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and so on.

The database however only has a column 'Rack' so I don't know which name to be using when identifying each fields...

Would it be something like this?

```
$builder
        ->add('rackno', 'integer', array(
                'label' => 'Rack: '
            )) // first rack #
        ->add('rackno', 'integer', array(
                'label' => 'To: '
            )) // last rack #
        ->add('Submit', 'submit');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
'mapped' => false
```

and set their names to `rackno_from` and `rackno_to`
to both fields in form so their value will not be assigned to `$object->rackno` field

then after the form is submitted, you can do whatever you want with the values and do inserts you want after the object is saved. So you would have:

```
$builder
        ->add('rackno_from', 'integer', array(
                'label' => 'Rack: ',
                'mapped' => false
            )) // first rack #
        ->add('rackno_to', 'integer', array(
                'label' => 'To: ',
                'mapped' => false
            )) // last rack #
        ->add('Submit', 'submit');
```

then after you submit the form

```
if($form->isValid())
{

// get the rackno_from and rackno_to from form and do what you need with those values

}
```